# How do I jump from line in Skim to the same line in my text editor?

Tags: forward-inverse-search

I set my text editor (Aquamacs) to produce the .synctex.gz file. But still I don't understand how to jump from Skim back into the text editor. Is there a specific command?

Answer (score 14):

I just found it out.
On Skim, Shift and Apple key then click on the PDF text.

Comment: Does the editor also need to be open, or will it call it?